# How to have the content fit whole screen with respect to the browser size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so this first section of my page will fit the whole browser, but I also want it to be responsive. The problem I have right now is that when I resize the browser, the text or some things may get cut off.

In the photo, you can see some of the text is cut off, but I don't want it to get cut off.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is make the top section fit the whole browser for any size, but also the content inside must be responsive as well.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e75q34ob/)

[image: Click here to see what I mean.]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap');
    
    body, html
    {
      background-color: #598392;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
      height:100%;
    }
    
    .menuIcon
    {
      padding:20px;
      display:none;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    
    .navigationBar
    {
      background-color: #124559;
      width:100%;
      overflow:hidden;
      position:fixed;
    
    }
    .title
    {
      overflow:hidden;
      height:100vh;
      
    }
    .navigationBar li
    {
      padding:20px;
      display: inline;
      list-style-type:none;
    
    }
    
    a
    {
      color: #EFF6E0;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover
    {
      color: #AEC3B0;
    }
    nav ul
    {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0;
      transition: max-height 1s;
    }
    
    .title h1
    {
      padding: 75px 0 0 20px;
    }
    .title article
    {
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .show
    {
        display:block;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
    {
      .menuIcon
      {
        display:block;
      }
    
      .navigationBar
      {opacity: 0.9;}
      .navigationBar li
      {
        display:block;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    
      }
      nav ul
      {
        max-height: 0;
        padding: 0px;
    
      }
    
      .show
      {
        max-height: 200px;
    
      }
      .title article
      {
        padding: 20px;
      }
    
    }
    /*
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
    {
      nav ul
      {
        display: block !important;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "nav.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class = "navigationBar">
        <img src = "https://i.imgur.com/nfbKl0W.png" class = "menuIcon">
        <ul class = "linkBar">
    
          <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#about" class = "aboutLink">About</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Media</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
    
        </ul>
      </nav>
    
      <section class = "title">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <article>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis vitae magna quis lacinia. Donec felis velit, consequat at nisi quis, sollicitudin scelerisque quam. Proin metus sapien, lobortis ac lacus a, maximus porttitor magna. Praesent pellentesque felis a consequat semper. Sed commodo gravida elit sit amet interdum. Suspendisse felis tellus, consequat vel varius eu, tincidunt eu elit. Quisque porttitor ultricies risus, at accumsan diam vehicula in. Aliquam sit amet arcu nec dui pretium viverra et eget ipsum. Mauris id diam sem. Etiam pellentesque eleifend odio non sagittis. Phasellus eleifend felis et convallis mollis. Donec eget diam nisl. Nam non molestie mi. Suspendisse vitae efficitur nisl. In ac urna at mi ultrices commodo.
        </article>
        <article>
        Vestibulum quis porttitor nisl, eget tincidunt ante. Ut ac fringilla nulla. Donec cursus est semper sodales mollis. In pellentesque   elementum porttitor. Curabitur aliquet velit risus, sed blandit nisl luctus cursus. Vivamus sem massa, cursus vitae ipsum fringilla, feugiat porta tellus. Fusce ac ornare nisi. Maecenas metus nibh, tincidunt vel sem vel, iaculis pharetra sem. Aenean dolor nisl, porta sit amet rutrum et, posuere nec nibh. Pellentesque ante nisi, molestie dignissim porttitor sit amet, dignissim ut magna.
        </article>
        <article>
        Vestibulum congue finibus felis suscipit pellentesque. Nunc pulvinar neque a ipsum molestie, condimentum congue urna hendrerit. Morbi egestas ac velit quis tincidunt. Donec consectetur finibus dui a consequat. Sed varius diam ut dui viverra, a pellentesque nunc molestie. Nullam tristique iaculis nibh, non posuere nunc scelerisque eu. Suspendisse dictum velit et felis lacinia ullamcorper.
      </article>
        <article>
        Suspendisse purus ipsum, fermentum ultricies nisl eu, condimentum luctus sem. In bibendum tristique elit, at luctus sem interdum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Cras id tellus at felis egestas pharetra ut eget massa. Aliquam sed euismod dolor. Vestibulum convallis sem vel rhoncus tincidunt. Nunc at dictum purus, sed imperdiet tellus. Suspendisse at justo quis ligula blandit euismod a eget urna. Maecenas quis ligula eget leo iaculis mattis. In et varius tellus. Quisque lacinia magna mi, nec molestie felis condimentum non. Nunc laoreet sem sit amet massa ultrices auctor. Aliquam a convallis lectus, ut sagittis massa.
      </article>
      <article>
        Nullam feugiat porttitor luctus. Vivamus ac imperdiet dui, in venenatis sapien. Maecenas faucibus nunc a ex hendrerit hendrerit eget at nisi. Praesent tempor dictum nulla. Nam mattis fringilla fermentum. Vestibulum iaculis, velit nec viverra consectetur, tellus leo eleifend quam, vel venenatis urna eros nec ipsum. Curabitur lobortis venenatis mauris eu viverra. Donec vel condimentum neque. Aenean molestie lectus a ante facilisis tincidunt. Cras urna purus, porta a lacinia in, varius quis leo. Fusce ligula velit, dapibus non dui nec, pharetra scelerisque nunc. Aliquam ut mattis leo. Maecenas vitae porttitor risus. Nunc euismod viverra condimentum. Aliquam sagittis, nibh quis rutrum tincidunt, purus ligula rhoncus quam, egestas semper nunc ante non mi. Aliquam eget enim aliquet, laoreet leo sit amet, finibus lorem.
        </article>
      </section>
    
      <section class = "about" id = "about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <article>
        Suspendisse purus ipsum, fermentum ultricies nisl eu, condimentum luctus sem. In bibendum tristique elit, at luctus sem interdum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Cras id tellus at felis egestas pharetra ut eget massa. Aliquam sed euismod dolor. Vestibulum convallis sem vel rhoncus tincidunt. Nunc at dictum purus, sed imperdiet tellus. Suspendisse at justo quis ligula blandit euismod a eget urna. Maecenas quis ligula eget leo iaculis mattis. In et varius tellus. Quisque lacinia magna mi, nec molestie felis condimentum non. Nunc laoreet sem sit amet massa ultrices auctor. Aliquam a convallis lectus, ut sagittis massa.
      </article>
      <article>
        Nullam feugiat porttitor luctus. Vivamus ac imperdiet dui, in venenatis sapien. Maecenas faucibus nunc a ex hendrerit hendrerit eget at nisi. Praesent tempor dictum nulla. Nam mattis fringilla fermentum. Vestibulum iaculis, velit nec viverra consectetur, tellus leo eleifend quam, vel venenatis urna eros nec ipsum. Curabitur lobortis venenatis mauris eu viverra. Donec vel condimentum neque. Aenean molestie lectus a ante facilisis tincidunt. Cras urna purus, porta a lacinia in, varius quis leo. Fusce ligula velit, dapibus non dui nec, pharetra scelerisque nunc. Aliquam ut mattis leo. Maecenas vitae porttitor risus. Nunc euismod viverra condimentum. Aliquam sagittis, nibh quis rutrum tincidunt, purus ligula rhoncus quam, egestas semper nunc ante non mi. Aliquam eget enim aliquet, laoreet leo sit amet, finibus lorem.
        </article>
      </section>
    
      <script>
    
        $('.menuIcon').on('click', function() {
          $('nav ul').toggleClass('show');
        });
    
        $('.aboutLink').on('click', function() {
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top}, 2000);
        });
    
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The text being cut off is due to the two css properties given to the title class

```
.title
{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100vh;
}
```

100vh means the div will be 100% of the view (usually the browsers) height. As the text spans more lines due to the lines getting thinner, the text will start to overflow. As the overflow of the div is set to hidden the text will be cut off.

This could be considered a fixed height and it is recommended not to give fixed heights to div's with content.

If you remove these two lines of code the text will not be cut off. If you would like to keep the height on larger screens you could use the following code to ensure that the height does not drop under 100vh

```
min-height:100vh;
```

Comment: When I remove the overflow:hidden, this happens: http://prntscr.com/hw4e0q

Comment: Just need to set the navbar `top:0;`

Comment: Right, the whole point of this was to make the whole section fit the entire page. The min-height fixed it, thanks. As for the nav bar being cut off, can you explain why without overflow:hidden, that nav bar gets cutoff on the top?

Comment: wasnt because overflow, it was the min-height that was pushing the navbar to the top if i am correct

Comment: due to the body having padding, the nav bar was fixed inside the body's padding. You could either set the padding of the body to 0, or the top position of the nav to 0

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap');
    
    body, html
    {
      background-color: #598392;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
      height:100%;
    }
    
    .menuIcon
    {
      padding:20px;
      display:none;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    
    .navigationBar
    {
      background-color: #124559;
      width:100%;
      overflow:hidden;
      position:fixed;
      top: 0;
    
    }
    .navigationBar li
    {
      padding:20px;
      display: inline;
      list-style-type:none;
    
    }
    
    a
    {
      color: #EFF6E0;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover
    {
      color: #AEC3B0;
    }
    nav ul
    {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0;
      transition: max-height 1s;
    }
    
    section h1
    {
      padding: 75px 0 0 20px;
    }
    section article
    {
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .show
    {
        display:block;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
    {
      .menuIcon
      {
        display:block;
      }
    
      .navigationBar
      {opacity: 0.9;}
      .navigationBar li
      {
        display:block;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    
      }
      nav ul
      {
        max-height: 0;
        padding: 0px;
    
      }
    
      .show
      {
        max-height: 200px;
    
      }
      .title article
      {
        padding: 20px;
      }
    
    }
    /*
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
    {
      nav ul
      {
        display: block !important;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "nav.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class = "navigationBar">
        <img src = "https://i.imgur.com/nfbKl0W.png" class = "menuIcon">
        <ul class = "linkBar">
    
          <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#about" class = "aboutLink">About</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Media</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
    
        </ul>
      </nav>
    
      <section class = "title">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <article>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis vitae magna quis lacinia. Donec felis velit, consequat at nisi quis, sollicitudin scelerisque quam. Proin metus sapien, lobortis ac lacus a, maximus porttitor magna. Praesent pellentesque felis a consequat semper. Sed commodo gravida elit sit amet interdum. Suspendisse felis tellus, consequat vel varius eu, tincidunt eu elit. Quisque porttitor ultricies risus, at accumsan diam vehicula in. Aliquam sit amet arcu nec dui pretium viverra et eget ipsum. Mauris id diam sem. Etiam pellentesque eleifend odio non sagittis. Phasellus eleifend felis et convallis mollis. Donec eget diam nisl. Nam non molestie mi. Suspendisse vitae efficitur nisl. In ac urna at mi ultrices commodo.
        </article>
        <article>
        Vestibulum quis porttitor nisl, eget tincidunt ante. Ut ac fringilla nulla. Donec cursus est semper sodales mollis. In pellentesque   elementum porttitor. Curabitur aliquet velit risus, sed blandit nisl luctus cursus. Vivamus sem massa, cursus vitae ipsum fringilla, feugiat porta tellus. Fusce ac ornare nisi. Maecenas metus nibh, tincidunt vel sem vel, iaculis pharetra sem. Aenean dolor nisl, porta sit amet rutrum et, posuere nec nibh. Pellentesque ante nisi, molestie dignissim porttitor sit amet, dignissim ut magna.
        </article>
        <article>
        Vestibulum congue finibus felis suscipit pellentesque. Nunc pulvinar neque a ipsum molestie, condimentum congue urna hendrerit. Morbi egestas ac velit quis tincidunt. Donec consectetur finibus dui a consequat. Sed varius diam ut dui viverra, a pellentesque nunc molestie. Nullam tristique iaculis nibh, non posuere nunc scelerisque eu. Suspendisse dictum velit et felis lacinia ullamcorper.
      </article>
        <article>
        Suspendisse purus ipsum, fermentum ultricies nisl eu, condimentum luctus sem. In bibendum tristique elit, at luctus sem interdum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Cras id tellus at felis egestas pharetra ut eget massa. Aliquam sed euismod dolor. Vestibulum convallis sem vel rhoncus tincidunt. Nunc at dictum purus, sed imperdiet tellus. Suspendisse at justo quis ligula blandit euismod a eget urna. Maecenas quis ligula eget leo iaculis mattis. In et varius tellus. Quisque lacinia magna mi, nec molestie felis condimentum non. Nunc laoreet sem sit amet massa ultrices auctor. Aliquam a convallis lectus, ut sagittis massa.
      </article>
      <article>
        Nullam feugiat porttitor luctus. Vivamus ac imperdiet dui, in venenatis sapien. Maecenas faucibus nunc a ex hendrerit hendrerit eget at nisi. Praesent tempor dictum nulla. Nam mattis fringilla fermentum. Vestibulum iaculis, velit nec viverra consectetur, tellus leo eleifend quam, vel venenatis urna eros nec ipsum. Curabitur lobortis venenatis mauris eu viverra. Donec vel condimentum neque. Aenean molestie lectus a ante facilisis tincidunt. Cras urna purus, porta a lacinia in, varius quis leo. Fusce ligula velit, dapibus non dui nec, pharetra scelerisque nunc. Aliquam ut mattis leo. Maecenas vitae porttitor risus. Nunc euismod viverra condimentum. Aliquam sagittis, nibh quis rutrum tincidunt, purus ligula rhoncus quam, egestas semper nunc ante non mi. Aliquam eget enim aliquet, laoreet leo sit amet, finibus lorem.
        </article>
      </section>
    
      <section class = "about" id = "about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <article>
        Suspendisse purus ipsum, fermentum ultricies nisl eu, condimentum luctus sem. In bibendum tristique elit, at luctus sem interdum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Cras id tellus at felis egestas pharetra ut eget massa. Aliquam sed euismod dolor. Vestibulum convallis sem vel rhoncus tincidunt. Nunc at dictum purus, sed imperdiet tellus. Suspendisse at justo quis ligula blandit euismod a eget urna. Maecenas quis ligula eget leo iaculis mattis. In et varius tellus. Quisque lacinia magna mi, nec molestie felis condimentum non. Nunc laoreet sem sit amet massa ultrices auctor. Aliquam a convallis lectus, ut sagittis massa.
      </article>
      <article>
        Nullam feugiat porttitor luctus. Vivamus ac imperdiet dui, in venenatis sapien. Maecenas faucibus nunc a ex hendrerit hendrerit eget at nisi. Praesent tempor dictum nulla. Nam mattis fringilla fermentum. Vestibulum iaculis, velit nec viverra consectetur, tellus leo eleifend quam, vel venenatis urna eros nec ipsum. Curabitur lobortis venenatis mauris eu viverra. Donec vel condimentum neque. Aenean molestie lectus a ante facilisis tincidunt. Cras urna purus, porta a lacinia in, varius quis leo. Fusce ligula velit, dapibus non dui nec, pharetra scelerisque nunc. Aliquam ut mattis leo. Maecenas vitae porttitor risus. Nunc euismod viverra condimentum. Aliquam sagittis, nibh quis rutrum tincidunt, purus ligula rhoncus quam, egestas semper nunc ante non mi. Aliquam eget enim aliquet, laoreet leo sit amet, finibus lorem.
        </article>
      </section>
    
      <script>
    
        $('.menuIcon').on('click', function() {
          $('nav ul').toggleClass('show');
        });
    
        $('.aboutLink').on('click', function() {
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top}, 2000);
        });
    
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```